# How can I access a method from another class?

Tags: iphone, class, shared

I know this question was already ask several times but i don't get it.

I have 2 classes classA.h & .m and classB.h and .m.

In classA.h i've got a `UITextField *myTextfield`.
In classB i import the header of classA and define the class with `@class classA`.
I also set `classA *classa`.

if i try to get the value of myTextfield like this myString = classA.myTextfield.text;
nothing happens

any suggestions what i'm doing wrong here?

i would be so thankfull for an answer becaus without getting this done i can't continue coding :)

thanks!

Comment: Does your value not get updated or your code fails to compile?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to access class properties (variables) not methods (the functions). There's plenty of beginner tutorials on the web. and here's the Objective-c 2.0 guide for Declared Properties: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

Comment: i had a problem with both values and method. I thought one solution would help me to solve both. i forgot to change the title sorry.

Comment: Can someone please have a look at my sample file?
Thanks so much!

http://rapidshare.com/files/306053664/sharedVariables.zip.html

Answer (score 1):

members of Objective-C classes are always private.

In order to access the members of another class, you need to create accessor methods to these properties. The easiest way to do this is is via properties.

Modifiy your classA.h to look like this

```
@interface classA : UITableViewController
{
  IBOutlet UITextField *myTextfield;
  ...
}
@property(retain, readonly) UITextField * myTextfield;
...
@end
```

Then modify classA.m to have

```
@implementation classA
@synthesize myTextfield;
```

Then when you need to use it in the other class use either

```
classa.myTextfield.text
```

Or preferably

```
[[classa myTextfield] text]
```

Edit:

Also make sure that myTextField is being set to some value, by hooking it up to some text field in Interface Builder. See a sample Interface Builder tutorial if this is the problem.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply!

So what is if i change for example UITabeViewController to SuperClass or UIViewController? Dosn't this have any influence on the behaviour of the classes?

Comment: SuperClass is just a placeholder for your current super class. Since it is a UITableViewController, I will edit the example to match.

Comment: and how do i call a method?

[classA addEntryToList];

that doesn't call the method but why? 

method looks like this:
- (void)addEntryToList;

thanks

Comment: in classA i set an NSString:
NSString *myString = @"viewDidLoad"; 

in classB i tried to get the value with:
NSString *mystring2 = [classA myString];

but that doesn't work. no compiler error only a warning because of an unused var.
:(